# Adding color under a curve, with AxesSubplot object (matplotlib & tkinter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using matplotlib module in order to draw graph in tkinter window.
I'm using AxesSubplot object to configure the graph's style.

My question is: How do I draw color under the curve of the graph, with this object (AxesSubPlot object)?
This is the code that I use to configure and draw the graph:

```
def graph_handle(self):

    canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.__fig, master=self.__SettingsFrame)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    self.__axes = self.__fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,axisbg='#221E1E')
    self.__axes.plot([0])
    self.__axes.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
    self.__axes.spines['top'].set_color('white')
    self.__axes.spines['left'].set_color('#221E1E')
    self.__axes.spines['right'].set_color('#221E1E')
    self.__axes.xaxis.label.set_color('#221E1E')
    self.__axes.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black')
    self.__axes.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#221E1E')

    self.__fig.gca().clear()
    self.__fig.gca().plot([0], [0])
    self.__fig.canvas.draw()
```

Of course I have the tkinter settings in the code and other stuff, If you think it's relevant, write this down in the comments and i'll add.

Thanks.

Edit:
So far, the code provides this graph:
[image]
And I want to add color under the curve (Between the curve and the down axis)(Sorry for the bad drawing, it's just a demonstration):
[image]

Edit2:

This is the function that I call whenever the array to plot is updated(i.e, when I need to update the graph, because there are more values in the array to plot then before):

```
def update_plot(self, txnamount):

    self.__GraphPlot[0].append(self.__TransactionsCurrently)
    self.__GraphPlot[1].append(self.__WalletBalance+txnamount)

    self.__axes.fill_between(self.__GraphPlot[0], self.__GraphPlot[1], facecolor="yellow")

    self.__fig.gca().clear()
    self.__fig.gca().plot(self.__GraphPlot[0], self.__GraphPlot[1], color="white", linewidth=0.8)
    self.__fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Axes.fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-fill-between). 
There is a nice example on the [matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

In this case you'd use

```
self.__axes.fill_between(x,y, facecolor='yellow')
```

where `x` and `y` are the array to plot.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added this line in the same function and nothing happened (x,y in my program are lists of positions, I tried to put them in the function just like you did, and also tried: np.asarray(x),np.asarray(y) and still nothing happened). I also tried to put this line in the function which updates the plot, and still nothing happened (I'll add the function which updates the graph with the update array to plot, to my question above, please check if there's the problem).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `axes.clear()` after plotting to the axes. This will simply remove the newly added `fill_between` plot.

Comment: Right, I don't know why did I put this line there.. Thanks!